# Continuity on subsets

Tags: continuity

If I define $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to be continuous on a subset $S\subset X$ if for any sequence $\{x_n\}\in S$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ implies that $f(x)\in f(S)$.

My question (and it could be a very dumb one, i just can't see why) is: if for any sequence $\{x_n\}\notin S$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ it means that $f(x)\notin f(S)$?

If there's an answer to that already, sorry, but i did not find it.

Comment: Your definition  of  continuous on $S$ disagrees with the usual one. For example if $X=Y=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$ then according to the usual def'n, $ f$  is continuous on every $S\subset X.$... But if $S=(0,1]$  and $x_n=1/n$ then $x_n\to 0$ but $f(0)=0\not \in (0,1[=f(S).$....  One of the many (equivalent)  usual definitions is that $f $ is continuous on $S\subset X$ iff    $[\;f(x) \in f(S)\cap Cl_Y(f(T))$  whenever $T\subset S$ and $x\in S\cap Cl_X(T)\;] ,$... where $Cl_X$ and $Cl_Y$ denote the closures in the spaces $X,Y.$

Comment: The definition of continuity can be fixed by changing $f(x)\in f(S)$ at the end of it to $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.  Then presumably the question would be changed so that the desired conclusion is $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$ instead of $f(x)\notin f(S)$.  Alternatively, you could keep $x_n\in S$ but assume $x_n\not\to x$ instead and still ask if $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$.  In both cases, the answer is No, it does not mean that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is negative. Take, for instance $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$. Then, bu your definition, $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Now, consider the sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Its elements don't belong to $[0,1]$. However, it converges to $1$ and $f(1)\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you very much!